# How to update (replace) a Postgis table?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, shapefile

I would like to "update" a "countries of the world"-postgis-table, by replacing it with another one which comes in form of a shapefile (dumped from a Postgis database) from my development server.

Now, I can't just do a "pgsql2shp", as this would throw an error as the table already exists. And renaming the existing table into something like "xx_original" doesn't work either ("xx_geom_gist already exists", is then the error message).

I don't want to delete the (old) table directly, as I would like to keep it as a backup.

So, what is the "right" way to solve this? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: If you get *xx_geom_gist already exists*" then choose a different name. Apparently this table has been "backed up" already.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to call it the same name, as the whole code on my website uses the table named "xx".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an upsert functionality the obvious approach if you are on PostgreSQL 9.1 or higher is to copy the data into a temporary table and then use a CTE to update.

An example might be:

```
 WITH upsert as (
     UPDATE my_countries set shape = (select shape from temp_countries t 
                                       where t.name = my_countries.name)
      WHERE name IN (select name from temp_countries)
    RETURNING *
 )
 INSERT INTO my_countries
 SELECT * FROM temp_countries
  WHERE name NOT IN (select name from upsert);
```